# Can I import and use MyBoy emulator's saves on the Bittboy PocketGo?

Tags: emulation, my-boy

I have used MyBoy's Link Local feature to trade all 3 starters on one Pokemon Emerald save. Now I would like to move that save into the Bittboy PocketGo and continue playing there.

Is this possible?